# Gradle Task Execution Skipped after commandLine in doFirst

Tags: windows, gradle

This is a build process on Windows.
I have gradle task (type: Exec) which uses its *doFirst* closure to temporarily copy a file from a foreign directory, which is required for its build process:

```
task(myTask, type: Exec) {
    [...]
    < do own stuff >
    [...]

    doFirst {
        println "Copy file"
        if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "copy .\\<myFile> .\\..\\.."
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, using *commandLine* within *doFirst*, to execute the copy command, makes the whole task terminate and prevents the execution of the task's main purpose.

Using switch *--debug* I took a look into the debug output and saw that the copy command makes the state to be changed to *succeeded*:

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'cmd'.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
[INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'command 'cmd''
[QUIET] [system.out]         1 file(s) copied.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task 'myTask'
```

How can I prevent this "commandLine" within *doFirst* to stop the task further execution?

Comment: why did you decide to use windows command line file copy instead of gradle copy task?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `commandLine` in `doFirst` closure just use plain old `copy` block:

```
task(myTask, type: Exec) {
    [...]
    < do own stuff >
    [...]

    doFirst {
        println "Copy file"
        copy {
           from "some file"
           into "some path"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain though why command line execution aborts remaining gradle task?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractExecTask.java). When `commandLine` is used an action is added (and replaces previously added actions) to task. After task is executed and `commandLine` was _used_ task status is changed to success and no further actions are taken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the copy block seems to be  executed asynchronously: In the debug logs can be seen the copy cmd terminating *after* the start of the main task. Can this be prevented?

Comment: @Windwalker can you please provide an example that reproduces the problem? You can also move the copy part to a separate task and define a dependency.

Comment: @Windwalker was my answer helpful or not?